# How can i Check whether user is Logged In Or Not In Symfony?

Tags: session, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm creating a job portal for my final year project. There i need to put session when job seeker applying for a particular vacancy when he/she click the "Apply" button check whether the user is logged with system or not. If he is logged user can proceed apply and upload a cv . else he should have to register with a system and when click apply page should redirect to register page. So how can i do this with symfony? 
Is it possible to do this session part inside "apply" button.. im not very familiar with symfony.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function in the sfBasicSecurityUser which tell you [if the user is connected](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfBasicSecurityUser.class.php#L172):

```
// in template
$sf_user->isAuthenticated();

// in action
$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated();
```

And before redirect the user to the login system, you can store the referer [using ->getReferer()](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/request/sfWebRequest.class.php#L337):

```
$request->getReferer();
```

And if you can, use [sfGuardDoctrinePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) to handle your user management (user, group, permission, login, register, etc ..)

**Edit:**

So, inside your login action, you add something like that:

```
// store the referer url in the session for a future use, if it's doesn't already exists
if($this->getUser()->getAttribute('referer_url', null, 'login'))
{
  $this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer_url', $request->getReferer(), 'login');
}
```

In your signin action:

```
// retrieve the referer in session, otherwise the one in request, otherwise redirect to homepage
$signinUrl = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('referer_url', $request->getReferer(), 'login');
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->remove('referer_url');

return $this->redirect('' != $signinUrl ? $signinUrl : '@homepage');
```

**Edit 2:**

And if you want a custom redirect, set it before the redirect to the login page:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer_url', 'my/custom/url', 'login');
```

Comment: inside my vacancySucess page i've use a link to apply job <a href="<?php echo url_for('vacancy/applyVacancy') ?>"><input type="submit"  value="Apply Now"/>  so what i want to know is can i use the session part when a person click the "Apply" button. So is it possible ?

Comment: yes, define your action `applyVacancy` as [secure](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security) and then your user will be redirect to the login page if he's not logged in.

Comment: in my applyVacancy action class i've put                          if ($request->isMethod('post')){
   $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('vacancy'), $request->getFiles('vacancy'));
 if ($this->form->isValid()){
$file = $this->form->getValue('file');
$filename=sha1($file->getOriginalName()).$file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
$file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$filename);
$this->redirect('vacancy/listAllVacancy');                          So before executing that part i need to put that redirecting part right? because from above code i used to uploading a cv .

Comment: so do i need to put 
applyVacancy:
  is_secure:  true
  credentials: ROLE_USER_HOME_PAGE in side security.yml page

Comment: If you use is_secure, you don't have to care about the redirection, symfony will handle it automatically.

Comment: yeah it help me a lot, thanks a lot for the help... one more thing to ask, here after put that secure method inside security.yml, if user not login with system, when he click apply button it will redirect to sign in page, so after sign in it will go to home page, because of my settings. So can I change it to link with applyVacancy page after login with system? Because what I want is when user login to system, straight away it will goes to vacancyApply page, so that he can apply for a vacancy..

Comment: If your are using sfGuard, it is normally handle [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/README#L406) and use the referer as default redirect.

Comment: the thing is we are not allowed to use any plugins for this project :(  is there any alternative ways?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can retrieve the referer from the request object to manually perform the redirect. Store it in your login action, not after.

Comment: this what inside my signin page                                       $user_session->setAuthenticated(true);
$user_session->clearCredentials();
$user_session->addCredential('ROLE_USER_HOME_PAGE');$this->redirect('@home_page');   so if i change redirect url it will affect to other pages as well...i didnt get the part u said "retrieve the referer " what it does mean?

Comment: in my user module there are no login page , i only  use userSigninAction.class & addNewUserAction.class. is it fine? and i have to mention refefre url as "applyvacancy" and signin url as "signin" isnt it?

Comment: Add the code to `userSigninAction` then, and you don't have to manually put `applyvacancy`, `$request->getReferer()` will do the job **automatically**.

Comment: in my system for sign in user need to go profile page and after sign in it will redirect to sign in page, so after using referer after login it will goes back to profile page, my initial system it was work like when sign in it goes to home page, can i change it ?

Comment: what i want is when user goes to profile , sign in form will appear, after signin it shoul goes to home page, but now it gos to profile page back. if i want to change to redirect home apge what can i do?

Comment: is it possible to use an "if" statement for doing this, i mean when user applying for a job it after sign in it should be go to applyVacancy page, and in all other situations whenever user signin with system it will redirect to home page?

Comment: this is what i really want - initially when an user registerd with a system, and sign in page should be redirect to the home page, and when user try to register with a system when he try to apply for a job , after regisretion n signin page should be redirect to the applyVacancy page back... how can i do this??

Comment: I told you on the 2nd edit ... just replace "my/custom/url" by your `applyVacancy` url.

Comment: yep i appliy that. but when i putting it like that way it works for vacancyapplying part. but the thing is whenever user login to system all the time now it redirect to apply vacancy page, i want to do that only when user applying for job only. for all other times if a user sign in or register page should go home page,,, is it possible to do?

Comment: The 2nd edit **should only be placed** for the `applyVacancy` not for all page, right?

Comment: hmm.. i think something wrong with the place i have put it on..    i have put it signin action.class page like this ---->>                                               $this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer_url', '@apply_vacancy');
                    $signinUrl = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('referer_url', $request->getReferer());
                    $this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->remove('referer_url');
                      return $this->redirect('' != $signinUrl ? $signinUrl : '@home_page');                  this how i put it , and it aplly for all the page :( pleaese guide me

Comment: Wrong. You have to put it in the `@apply_vacancy` action. So when the user will be redirect to the login, the `referer_url` will be the one from `apply_vacancy`.

Comment: i wont work. i put it inside applyVacancy actionclass.php.. how it combied with signinaction.class ? im not clear about that?

Comment: @j0k-wht does the dis code line mean "return $this->redirect('' != $signinUrl ? $signinUrl : '@homepage');" because it seem like not working for me.in which situation it should be redirect to homepage, as you said i have put custom redirect to sign in when applying for a vacancy,

Comment: so tht accoriding to tht code all other instancese when user sign in it should be redirect to @homepage right?

Comment: bt in my case, for user to signin he should go to profile page and then only signin form display,so that after signin it redirect to same page(@profile)i want it to make redirect @homepage. how can i do this?@j0k please help..

Comment: thanks .. now it works ... if you dont mine can you please tell me what does this code do "return $this->redirect('' != $signinUrl ? $signinUrl : '@homepage');" because i 'm not clear abt that..

Comment: Simply: if `$signinUrl` is not empty, redirect to $signinUrl otherwise to @homepage.

Comment: there is one more question i have to ask, in my system when user applying for a job i want to check whether is he already upload a cv inside jobseeker profile or not.. if he upload cv there, hecan straight a way proceed, else he have to upload a cv.. how can i do this

Comment: <?php echo link_to('<input type="submit"  value="Apply Now"/>','vacancy/applyVacancy?vacancy_id='.$value->getVacancyId())?>
 this is the link im passing to go to applyVacancy page, i want to check whether user has upload a cv inside jobseekerRegistration or not..

Comment: readVacancy.success -            '<?php echo link_to('<input type="submit"  value="Apply Now"/>','vacancy/applyVacancy?vacancy_id='.$value->getVacancyId())?>'

Comment: readVacancy.action-                                                   ------------------------------------------                   
        $cvstatus= $request->getParameter('user_id');
        if($cvstatus==1) {
            $this->status = $this->getVacancyManagementService()->getUserById($cvstatus);

            $this->redirect('vacancy/listAllVacancy');
        }
        elseif($cvstatus==NULL) {
 $this->status = $this->getVacancyManagementService()->getUserById($cvstatus);
           $this->redirect('vacancy/applyVacancy');
        }

    }

Comment: when clicking apply now button system should check jobseeker table, whther cvstatus is 1 or null, if it is 1, then that mean cv is already uploaded, else it should goes to applyVacancy page  @j0k please do me favour up strugle with this part today morning onwards

Answer (score 0):

If you store user session manually like that:

```
// in action<br>
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('user', $user);
```

you can check for this user like that:

```
// in action
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('user');
```

then you can check for existing of user object ...